# How can I control table name when multiple tables are selected?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and I selected three tables in one statement like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_i, tb_s, tb_t
```

But I need case control by their table names. If a row from `tb_s` it returns `tb_s` on additional column `table_name`.

How can I get table name from this statement?

Comment: The answer to your questions is in the documentation of the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

The way you add up your tables now is a **JOIN** - meaning that every row is a Cartesian product of three of them - so each row is returned from **all the three tables**.

If you would like to concatenate the data from the three tables you should use **UNION ALL** which assumes that the columns are of the same structure. Then you would able to mark the origin table, with an addition constant field.

For instance in your case:

```
SELECT tb_i.*,'tb_i' as source
FROM tb_i
UNION ALL
SELECT tb_s.*,'tb_s'
FROM tb_s
UNION ALL
SELECT tb_t.*,'tb_t'
FROM tb_t
```

where the **source** column is a constant string per each table.